# Hiding Image on tabBarController

Tags: swift, image, tabbar

I've got a tab bar like this:
[image: tabBarimage]

The middle button is just a UIImage that is added in a sub-class of the tabBarController like so:

```
class TabBarDelegate: UITabBarController {

    let button = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        button.image = UIImage(named: "tabBarAdd")
        button.setImageColor(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.184496969, green: 0.6701939702, blue: 0.3898918033, alpha: 1))
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "tabBarAdd")
        imageView.bounds = CGRect(x: button.frame.origin.x, y: button.frame.origin.y, width: button.frame.width, height: button.frame.height)
         self.view.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: self.tabBar)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 17.5, y: self.view.bounds.height - 80, width: 35, height: 35)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5
    }
}
```

My image isn't currently the correct color so I'm using an extention to change the color, which is the `button.setImageColor(color: _)` function in the code.

The middle button is working fine when I press it, the touch just goes through the image and to the tabBarItem.

**What I would like to do is when there's a transition to the middle view controller, to hide the image.**

I've tried using the `viewDidAppear()` function in the viewController that's appearing. I used this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let tabBarD = TabBarDelegate()
    tabBarD.button.isHidden = true
}
```

but that's not working. I've also tried removing the image from the superview entirely using `tabBarD.button.removeFromSuperview()` but even that doesn't work.

I'd love any ideas and help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Thank you to emrepun who got me started thinking in a different way on how to solve it!

I ended up using an extension to the delegate method like so:

```
extension TabBarDelegate: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
            self.button.isHidden = true
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

And since I was using the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` method from the storyboard this worked!

Thanks for your time

Comment: This approach looks nice, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidAppear` method of `middleViewController`, you are actually initializing a new `TabBarController`, thats why it does not work in the way you intend.

Delete that code, and add two methods to your base `ViewControllers` in `tabBarController`, `viewWillDisAppear`, and `viewWillAppear`:

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWilDisappear(animated)
    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarDelegate {
        tabBarController.button.isHidden = true
    }

}

func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWilAppear(animated)
    if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as? TabBarDelegate {
        tabBarController.button.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

So each time you will go to another viewController (presumably detail viewController, from the base controllers of a tabBarController, you hide it when one of the baseViewController's view is going to disappear, then you make it visible again if the view is going to appear again.

Comment: Sorry this didn't work. The tab Bar isn't having the viewWillApear and disappear methods called when it's shown on the middleViewController

Comment: Try in your middleViewController, update your viewWillAppear method in your controller, wherever you write that as my implementation. Then also add viewWillDisAppear, and hide it as I did for your middleViewController as well.